# Word for 'Lacking a subject'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The poet Medbh McGuckian often lacks subjects in her sentences, for example:

"From behind the moon boys' graves \ bleed endlessly"
~ From *Love Affair with Firearms*

She doesn't ever define the subject of the sentence, is there a word for this or literary device?

Comment: Have you another example? One that truly lacks a subject? _Boys' graves_ is the subject here. It's just not in the usual initial position in the sentence, but this is hardly earth-shattering. 'From under the sofa, a mouse ran into the hall.' 'After the game, we left.'

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is such a literary device – this just isn't an example of it. (And I don't know whether it has a name, but I'd be interested in learning it if there is.)

Answer (score 1):

> From behind the moon boys' graves
>    bleed endlessly; from photograph
>    to browning photograph they blacken
>    headlines, stranded outside of time
>    at the story's frigid edge.

The subject in this stanza is the dead boys' (or their graves); if you rearrange the sentences (allowing for differing interpretations, and given that this is a poem about gun violence), they read (with explanation of prepositional phrases):

Boys' graves bleed endlessly from behind the moon (eternal night);
Their blood blackens the headlines from photograph to browning photograph (over time, they/their stories all become the same);
They are stranded outside of time at the story's frigid edge (the cold earth).

I read the entire poem, and did not find a sentence without a subject.

There is great license in poetry. Poems have subjects; if they are not named, they might be alluded to; if they have no identifiable subject, then the subject is the poem itself. If it's simply that the structure of the sentence is not the usual S-V-O pattern, it's called *hyperbaton*: a literary device wherein the author plays with the regular positioning of words and phrases and creates a differently structured sentence to convey the same meaning.

Comment: @Edwin already commented that OP's example does in fact have a subject, but that's not really relevant to the actual question being asked, and which you haven't addressed at all - *"Is there a word for this literary device?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If the OP doesn't recognize that his poem has a subject, his question is based on a misunderstanding. You know, like a question based on a typo. First you address the typo, no? "**She doesn't ever define the subject of the sentence**, is there a word for this or literary device?"

Comment: We get lots of questions where the *only* reason the poster has asked is because of a mistake or misunderstanding, and in those cases I generally think they should simply be closed (with a comment explaining exactly what's wrong). But in this case the question itself is unaffected by whether or not the example is a valid instance of "a sentence without a subject".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we disagree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with medica: the problem is that the OP has not managed to characterise the literary device they are asking about; we can only guess what they mean.

Comment: @Colin: I'd be astonished if there was actually a word for the "literary device" of omitting a subject (if they did teach me that in my Lit Crit degree, I've obviously forgotten it! :) But OP *identifies* the thing he wants to know the name of *three times* - once in the title, and twice in the text. The subject/object of the question seems clear to me, regardless of whether it cites a valid example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for pointing out that the question still remains intact. As for the validity of the example, in this case you could interpret it differently. Something is bleeding endlessly, the reader does not know what, yet we know it exists behind the moon boys' graves. Thus it lacks the primary subject of the sentence.

Comment: @HunterLarco - please read again; Fumble Fingers is *not* saying your sentence lacks a subject. It does not. This is simple hyperbaton. The subject *is* Boys' graves.

Comment: @HunterLarco: From your previous comment, it looks as if you think that _moon boys' graves_ is a noun phrase. If that is so, then the sentence does lack a subject. I (and I suspect the others who have commented) did not even notice this possibility, and parsed it as _behind the moon / boys' graves_, two separte NP's.

Comment: @HunterLarco - Read poetry any way you like; you won't be arrested; However, if you want to read English, there are syntactic features you need to pay attention to.  **This** is not a sentence: *Brambles blue an pottery quickly.* You can't pretend it is because you want it to be. Your poem is not filled with subjectless sentences. It's about something: **gun violence/death of young men through time, from world wars to today.** Every sentence in your poem has a natural subject. If you find me a poem in Chinese, I won't argue about it, because I don't *know* Chinese. I DO *know* English.