# What literary device is this?

Tags: single-word-requests, poetry, literary-techniques

I have been stumped in characterizing Medbh McGuckian's style of poetry: she often vividly describes the actions of things in her works to imply what they are. For example, within the context of war, the following stanza could be read such that "From behind the moon boys' graves \ bleed endlessly" refers to the mothers or lovers of dead men sent off to war. Thus making sense of the next clause "from photograph to browning photograph they blacken headlines"- referring to the newspapers held by the indicated lovers to remember their loved ones who died. The later would be perhaps imagery, but what of the first?

> From behind the moon boys' graves
>   bleed endlessly; from photograph
>   to browning photograph they blacken
>   headlines, stranded outside of time
>   at the story's frigid edge.

I wouldn't call this metaphor because two objects aren't being compared, rather they are being described. Yet I wouldn't call it imagery because she isn't describing the scene, but instead the very nature of her subjects.

Would this be metonymy, ambage, or something else?

Comment: It is a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor). Graves do not bleed.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Consider "moon boys'" as a noun phrase, not two nouns. In that case it isn't metaphor

Comment: If it was "like bleeding graves" it would be simile. "Graves bleed" makes it metaphor. This is still just a comment. Someone else may yet come up with a more full answer.

Comment: If you don't like the way your [earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165783/word-for-lacking-a-subject) is going, you should edit the original rather than repost it.

Comment: Why isn't the poet describing a scene? I interpret the boys' graves in a cemetery, row upon row of grave stones, acting like headlines, creating long shadows (bleeding) because the moonlight is behind them. They are also compared to *browning* photographs, which remind me of the [sepia toned](http://agnew.roominate.com/features/sepia_tone.htm) ones, typical of the early 20th century, the colour reminiscence of blood. Isn't this descriptive of a scene, the cemetery, comparing the grave stones with aged photographs? Isn't this metaphorical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>From behind the moon boys' graves

bleed endlessly; from photograph

to browning photograph they blacken

headlines, stranded outside of time

at the story's frigid edge.</sub>

That is an interesting interpretation. I'd like to challenge you, however, to consider (and answer):
a. Why are they called moon boys?
b. Why are the mothers and lovers (I like your interpretation that their handling of the paper blackens it) behind, or if they are not behind, what is?
c. Who or what is stranded outside of time at the story's frigid edge, and why?

If these are difficult to answer (as in, that's my point! There's no subject!), please consider the literary device called **hyperbaton**:

> A literary device wherein the author plays with the regular positioning of words and phrases and creates a differently structured sentence to convey the same meaning.

That would rearrange more normally to

Boys' graves bleed endlessly from behind the moon;
they blacken headlines from photograph to browning photograph
stranded outside of time at the story's frigid edge.

Here, the subject is *boys' graves*, they *bleed* blackening headlines, etc.

You need to ask yourself, before you ask for a literary device in which there are no subjects, which interpretation makes more sense?

Poems have subjects; if they are not named, they are alluded to; if they have no identifiable subject, then the subject is the poem itself.

<sub>you might be interested in [this](http://muse.jhu.edu/books/9781908634016).</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The device is named antonomasia n. -

> In rhetoric, antonomasia is a substitution of any epithet or phrase
>   for a proper name, such as "the little corporal" for Napoleon I.

-Wikipedia

> These and such other speaches, where ye take the name of the Author
>   for the thing it selfe; or the thing co- teining, for that which is
>   contained, & in many other cases do as it were wrong name the person
>   or the thing. So neucrthelesse as it may be vnderstood, it is by the
>   figure *metonymia*', or misnamer.
>
> **And if this manner of naming of persons or things be not by** (Please note postil: Antonomasia, or the Surnamer) 
>   **way of misnaming as before, but by a conuenient difference, and  such as is true or esteemed and likely to be true, it is then called
>   not *metonimia*, but *antonomasia***, **or the Surnamer,** (**not the
>   misna- mer, which might extend to any other thing aswell as to a
>   person**)** as he that would say : not king Philip of Spaine, but the
>   Westerne king, because his dominio lieth the furdest West of any
>   Christen prince: and the French king the great *Vallois*, because so
>   is the name of his house, or the Queene of England, *The maiden
>   Queene*, for that is her hiest peculiar among all the Queenes of the
>   world, or as we said in one of our *Partheniades*, the *Brylon mayde*,
>   because she is the most great and famous mayden of all Brittayne:
>   thus,
>
> *But in chaste stile, am borne as I weene To blazonfoorth the Brytton mayden Queene.* So did our forefathers call *Henry the first,
>   Beauclerke*, *Edmund Ironside*, R*ichard cceur de lion*: *Edward the
>   Confessor*, and we of her Maiestie *Elisabeth* the peasible. Then also
>   is the sence figuratiue when we deuise a new name  (Please note
>   postil:Onemetopeia, or the New namer.)  to any thing consonant, as
>   neere as we can to the nature thereof,  as to say: *flashing of
>   lightning*, *clashing of blades*, *clinking of fetters*, 'chinking of
>   mony':  & as the poet 'Virgil' said of the sounding a trum- pet,
>   *ta-ra-tant*, *taratantara*, or as we giue special names to the voi- ces of dombe beasts, as to say, a horse neigheth, a lyo brayes, a
>   swine grunts, a hen cackleth, a dogge howles, and a hundreth mo such
>   new names as any man hath liberty to deuise, so it be fittie for the
>   thing which he couets to expresse.

-Ancient critical essays upon English poets and ... v.1. Haslewood, Joseph, ed. 1769-

Despite anthorisms, this appears to be luculent.

Comment: That applies to a proper name, does that still apply here then? All the examples online seem to use this device to represent people's names and not objects.

Comment: isn't that an analogy too? Maybe even a metphor.